# run scala program in java jar file

Tags: eclipse, scala

I am trying to run Scala program through a jar file. I created the jar file but it can't find the main method in the program. I read somewhere that it is unable to find the Scala library so I ran the command below; but I am getting the following error:

```
[root@01HW394486 Desktop]# java -cp /opt/eclipse/plugins/org.scala-ide.scala210.jars_4.3.0.201512011535/target/jars/scala-library.jar -jar Test3.jar 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Predef$
    at TestDemo.funct1(MainClass1.scala:4)
    at MainClass1$.main(MainClass1.scala:10)
    at MainClass1.main(MainClass1.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Predef$
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 3 more
```

Please help...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try java -cp all-involvedjar-included-Test.jar3 mainClassPackageLocation
Something like: `java -cp scala-library.jar:test-hello_2.10-0.1.0.jar com.salc2.Main`

Comment: I tried but got following error:

[root@01HW394486 Desktop]# java -cp scala-library.jar,MainClass1.jar com.sample.MainClass1
Error: Could not find or load main class com.sample.MainClass1

Thanks.

Comment: try inspect copiled classes with javap command.. maybe MainClass1 is MainClass1$ @ghost0806

Comment: soprry it is colon separeted, something like: `java -cp scala-library.jar:test-hello_2.10-0.1.0.jar com.salc2.Main` @ghost0806

Comment: hey...it worked like this: "java -cp scala-library.jar:Test3.jar com.sample.MainClass1"     thanks a lot @salc2

Comment: but I would like to know if their is another easier way rather than running the jar like this through such a long command. Means I am expecting something like the short java command: "java -jar Myjarfile.jar". Appreciate your help.

Comment: For that inside your jar must to be a manifest file telling what is the main class.. search for how to do that with the tools you are using for build sbt, maven, etc. @ghost0806